# How do I fetch a single branch using Git SVN fetch?

Tags: git, svn, branch, git-svn, git-extensions

I am working with the Git SVN plugin with a SVN repository, every timeI do a git fetch it fetches all the branches changes all over SVN repository. it takes a long time after couple of hours with many commits over many branches

Can I tell it to fetch changes only for specific branches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch the remote branch corresponding to your current HEAD by using `git svn fetch --parent`.

It's not possible to fetch from a single remote Subversion branch that isn't the parent branch, sadly. You can kick of a `git svn fetch` in the background, though; it won't affect your working copy at all. I have my computer set up to do the fetch automatically overnight using `cron`.

Answer (score 0):

[git-svn man page](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-svn.html)

check these:

```
git-svn init --ignore-paths=<regex>  
git-svn fetch --ignore-paths=<regex>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have experienced the same problem. Our solution was (to our great satisfaction) not to use fetch on SVN but to let `git` import all SVN tags, branches and trunk to `git`-like structure.

Our SVN repository wasn't even properly created (trunk/tags/branch directories), but it didn't matter.

```
git svn --tags PATH_TO_YOUR_TAGS --branches PATH_TO_YOUR_BRANCHES --trunk PATH_TO_YOUR_TRUNK svn+ssh://path.to.your.svn/repository
```

This will take really long time. After this, workflow is `git`-like. You commit and make branches like in `git`, then...

commit to SVN:

```
git svn dcommit
```

checkout from SVN: (in diff)

```
git svn rebase
```